# IO Issue - Byte Array Image into XHTML(FlyingSaucer)

Tags: java, file-io, xhtml, arrays, flying-saucer

I have a solution that inserts strings into an XHTML document and prints the results as Reports. My employer has asked if we could pull images off their SQL database (stored as byte arrays) to insert into the Reports.

I am using FlyingSaucer as the XHTML interpreter and I've been using Java DOM to modify pre-stored reports that I have stored in the Report Generator's package.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to construct the images, save them as a file, link the file in an img tag (or background-image) in a constructed report, print the report and then delete the file. This seems really sloppy and I imagine it will be very time consuming.

I can't help but feel there must be a more elegant solution. Any suggestions for inserting a byte array into html?

Comment: Why won't you use [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)?

Comment: I've never used Data URIs. If you put up an answer detailing roughly how that might be done with example (and it works of course), then I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the image and convert it into it's Base64-encoded form:

   ```
   InputStream image = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.png");
   String encodedImage = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(ByteStreams.toByteArray(image));
   ```

   I've used [`BaseEncoding`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) and [`ByteStreams`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) from [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).
2. Change `src` attribute of `img` element within your `Document` object.

   ```
   Document doc = ...; // get Document from XHTMLPanel.getDocument() or create
                       // new one using DocumentBuilderFactory 

   doc.getElementById("myImage").getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").setNodeValue("data:image/png;base64," + encodedImage);
   ```
3. Unfortunatley FlyingSaucer does not support DataURIs out-of-the-box so you'll have to create your own `ReplacedElementFactory`. Read [Using Data URLs for embedding images in Flying Saucer generated PDFs](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-data-urls-for-embedding-images-in-flying-saucer-generated-pdfs/) article - it contains a complete solution.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to convert the image to Base64-encoded form in the standard Java library? My list of libraries is already too long on this project.

Comment: IIRC there is no standard Base64 encoder for JSE. There's plenty libraries out there, you could also write your very own (see: http://www.wikihow.com/Encode-a-String-to-Base64-With-Java ) Basic Base64 encoding is trivial.

Comment: @RudiKershaw If you are using the Sun JDK, then you have `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. But this is undocumented, and hence may be removed without notice with any new (maybe even bug fix) release of the JDK.

Comment: Doesn't look like I am going to get the time to test and implement this before the bounty runs out, so I am going to give you the benefit of the doubt. Thanks again. = )